# Sprites for Text Files

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Multiple images can be put into a single image file and then referenced via CSS individually.
This reduces GET requests.

Does anyone do anything similar for html, javascript, and CSS files, i.e. text files?

Basically put them in one static file in the server, sent to the client as 1 Get request, and then is parsed into separate files for insertion into the DOM

This would reduce multiple GET requests, similar to Sprites.

Comment: How's that any different than putting all your JS into one file, all your CSS into another, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sometimes done.  The [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/), for example, includes [functionality to create a custom build](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/custom-builds.html) via a small Java utility which gathers all the needed JavaScript components, and combines & compresses them into a single file.  It likewise copies all included CSS into a single file and brings inline any `@import` calls.

Beyond advanced functionality like Dojo's there's nothing stopping you from simply dumping all your CSS into the `<head><style/></head>` and your scripts into `<head><script/></head>`.  It is not considered a best practice, however, as it can impede code reuse unless you have configured a CMS to do the insertion and style in-lining for you (like Dojo does for JS and associated components).

Comment: I'm talking about all static content...html, javascript, css...into one .txt file...which is parsed at the client.

Comment: @CS_2013 You can already do that by simply putting all your JS in `<script>` tags and bringing all your CSS into `<style>` in the `<head>`  However, it isn't always considered a best practice.  It needn't be a .txt. The .html can handle all that stuff just as it is.

Comment: But streaming it in and placing it in the DOM programatically gives you more control...then statically serving it.